La Salle Invariance in Hilbert Spaces (Reference Request)
I’m trying to understand how La Salle invariance works in Hilbert spaces. Poking around, I found the following result of Jack Hale (Theorem 1 in this paper)
Theorem: Let $u$ be a dynamical system on a Banach space $\mathcal{B}$. If $V$ is a Lyapunov function on $G \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ and an orbit $\gamma^+(\phi)$ belongs to $G$ and is contained in a compact subset of $\mathcal{B}$, then $u(t, \phi) \rightarrow M$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$, where $M$ is the largest invariant set contained in $\{ \phi \in \overline{G} : \dot{V}(\phi) = 0 \}$.
This theorem is great, but the condition that the positive orbit must be pre-compact is quite restrictive. I’m wondering if there is a more practical result if we restrict to Hilbert spaces. I haven’t been able to find much poking around online, but I’m hopeful that someone might have a reference or two.
One thing that gives me hope is that Hale constructs a class of Banach spaces (including a Hilbert space) in which all bounded trajectories are pre-compact for a certain autonomous system. Since I’m mostly interested in autonomous systems, if autonomous dynamical systems had this property more generally in Hilbert spaces that would be extremely useful to me.
